# Fascinating (Secret) hat on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2014, secret-hats

How did I earn the *Fascinating* (secret) hat on Stack Overflow?
There is no clear explanation on the [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) page for it, just *this is a secret hat*!

Comment: [You upvoted an accepted answer with 5 votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245173/203057)

Comment: isn't asking for how to unlock it kind of against the spirit of the secret hats?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's because it is a secret.